# Recursion using Angularjs and Append Elemnts to an HTML Template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am quite new to Angularjs . I am working on an app which use Angularjs for front end and django-tastypie for back end. What I am doing is i have a topics list where topics are nested in each others as child parents for multiple levels. these levels can be multiple. my data structure is as

```
[{'id':1,
   'name':'science',
   'subtopics':[{
                 'id':1,
                  'name':'chemistry',
                   'subtopics':[{'id':1,
                                 'name':'atom',
                                  'subtopics':[{'id':1,'name':'science',:'subtopics':[]]
]]}}
```

I may have this nested list for multiple levels . What i want to do is that i want to do is that if I select an element from select list which has subtopics, a HTML  is appended to the template and selected elements subtopics become its elements . If there is only one level there will be only one select menu on the template.
Tell me how can I represent this tree in Template using angular. or tell if anyone have any better idea.

my desired HTML rendering is like

```
<label>Topic Level 1:</label>
<select ng-model="qt_topic_level_1" ng-options="topic.name for topic in qt_topicslist_level_1" ng-change="showSecondLevelTopics()">
</select></br>
<label ng-show="secondleveltopicslabel" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false">Topic Level 2:</label>
<select ng-model="qt_topic_level_2" ng-options="topic.name for topic in qt_topicslist_level_2" ng-change="getThirdleveltopics()" ng-show="secondleveltopicslist" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" >
</select></br>
```

means if the subtopics are available in the selected topics list a select tag should be appended to the template to select the sub topic and so on. First time I want to show the root elements only. and then on click want to show the subtopics level by level.

Comment: Can you give an example of the desired rendered html?

Comment: Fresheyeball, I have edited the question with the required rendered HTML

Comment: Right now I am doing this by Showing the hidden elements if the selected topic has some subtopics. but i know it is limited and not the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split your template in to two. The first one can by used as recursion container, the "main" topics template:

```
<div ng-repeat="topic in topics">
  <div include-tpl="path/to/topic/tpl-recursive"></div>
</div>
```

And the single topic's template:

```
<div class="topic">
  <!-- ..topic content.. -->

  <div class="subtopics">
     <div ng-repeat="topic in topic.subtopics">
       <div include-tpl="path/to/topic/tpl-recursive"></div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I use custom include-tpl directive because ngInclude creates new scope (or used to create, I'm currently using a bit dated version of angular):

```
.directive('includeTpl', ['$compile', '$http', function($compile, $http){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        var replace = typeof $attrs.replace !== 'undefined';
          $scope.$watch($attrs.includeTpl, function(value) {
            if (!value) return;
            $http.get(value).then(function(html){
              var content = $compile(html)($scope);
              if (replace) $element.replaceWith(content);
              else $element.html(content);
            });
           });
    }
  };
}])
```

Comment: Thanx, but can't it be done with a simple method. without using other template. means like javascript looping in the controller and appending the elements on the teplate???

Comment: If you want to access DOM or append elements in template, there is no need to use angularJS, because it will not fit this mindset. Nested structures are not simple - no matter which layer (controller or the view) processes it, you have to use recursion.

Comment: Okay thanx , now i dropped the idea of recursion. now i simply want to append a HTML select tag to the document if a user chhose a topic which has subtopics. and if they dont have subtopics nothing would happen

Comment: But your topics array is still nested in unlimited levels of depth? Or is it just topics and 1 level of subtopics?

Comment: yeah, you are right, topics array is still nested. But the problem i faced in terms of recursion is fetching a lot of records at once. Those many records also which I ll not use anywhere. and problem of sending a huge data to the browser. because these topics may be more than ten thousand at a time. Now what I am doing is I added a boolean yes or no at the place of subtopics. If a topic has somesubtopics means boolean is true i ll send a request to server to fetch those subtopics where they also have a boolean field about the subtopics.

Comment: Now when i will recieve those subtopics i want to append a <select></select> tag to the document which contains those subtopics as options. Hope things will be clear to you now.

Comment: If you still wanna do this in angular way, you will not append select. You will add `subtopics` property and let the angular worry about representing it in DOM. Either way there is absolutely no way to do this without recursion in templates if you do not know the depth of the whole tree. What is the problem with my solution?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41240/discussion-between-user1765969-and-package)

Comment: No, there is no problem with your solution but the problem is that i am fetching a huge data from database and sending a huge data to the client browser. there are only a few main topics but they have so many subtopics which i don't required.rather than fetching a big data i m using boolean and sending request to server to fetch the relavent data. becuase there may be conditions where a topic has multiple level of subtopics but user needs on 2 level of topic. but if i do it in this way it will fetch all the levels of subtopics at a time.i am showing you the structure i am using now to do this